# Erase or hide custom reports

Tags: commcare

I have a set of custom reports on CommCareHQ that would like to erase or hide as they aren't in use anymore. What would be the process to erase them?

Comment: You should submit a support request.

Answer (score 2):

**To delete a custom report**, or user configurable report (UCR), in CommCare, follow these steps:

1. navigate to the project space's configurable reports page: https://www.commcarehq.org/a/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME_HERE/configurable_reports/
2. select the report you'd like to delete, and at the bottom right of the page, click on the red "Delete Report" button

If you want to **keep the report but just hide it from a specific user**, you can follow these steps:

1. navigate to the Users tab in your project space, and select 'web users and roles'
2. create a web user and when defining the role's access, de-select the 'Views all Reports' checkbox. When you do this, a list of all reports in the domain will appear, and you can select exactly which reports that role can see. Exclude the custom reports you'd like to hide.
3. once you've saved the role, you can add specific email addresses to that role, and they won't see the reports you excluded.